# Compare Elements via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, compare

I'm in a situation where I want to check if two elements (one is clicked and another one a reference) are the same, what I'm trying to do is:

```
$("#process li").click(function() {
   currentElement = $(this);
   referenceElement = $("#process li:first-child");
   if (currentElement === referenceElement) {
        $(".mark").removeClass("mark");
        $(this).addClass("mark");
   }
});
```

So what I want is to check if the clicked `<li>` is the first child of the `ul#process` and if so first remove a .mark class from another element and then add it to the clicked one. I don't get any working result - ideas anyone?

---

UPDATE:

Thanks you very much! This is my solution:

```
$("#processlist li").click(function() {
  currentElement = $(this);
  if (currentElement.is('li:first-child')) {
    $(this).addClass("mark");
  }
});
```

Now if I click on a

, if it is the first child of this list, the class .mark is added - sweet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing objects in JS is very troublesome. The simplest way is to just pick a few key properties and compare those, eg:

```
if (currentElement.prop('id') === referenceElement.prop('id') {
    // rest of your code...
}
```

However, given your use case you could use `is`:

```
if (currentElement.is('#process li:first-child')) {
    // rest of your code...
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mr3x5Lyt/)

Comment: yeah it seems so, tried every way that came in my mind, just wanted to see if someone has a better idea than this key property solution - thank you!

Comment: well that's pretty smart, also thank you for the fiddle! Going to have a look at this solution, seems like the easiest way - thank you very much!

Comment: Also did not find any solution here on Stackoverflow. Going to implement it - your fiddle works like a breeze, however I'm not sure it is working together with the .click and $(this) thingy: http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/3t0573zt/6/

Comment: Yeah it's just an excerpt of a bigger project, am using the counter for a later thingy. I figured out your solution works pretty fine! I just had modify the code a bit more, going to update this post.

Comment: You're comparing `#processlist li` to `#process li:first-child` - the containers are different so the `li` will never be the same. If you make them the same it works: http://jsfiddle.net/3t0573zt/8/

Comment: yep, that was the problem, guess that happens if you are working on something for too long ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the DOM element from the jQuery object.  You can use the `get` method of jQuery for this.

e.g. `if( currentElement.get( 0 ) === referenceElement.get( 0 ) )`